# What collection do I need to return to support filtering in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, data-binding

I have a WCF client that I need to put a DTO in to a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx), however when I attempt to apply a filter to the BindingSource it does not work as neather List nor BindingList because both of them return false for `IBindingListView.SupportsFiltering`.

What datatype do I need to be using to be able to filter on my lists?

The proxy DTO:

```
namespace MyApp.DataContracts
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "ServerSetupDTO", Namespace = "http://example.com/MyApp")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class ServerSetupDTO : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.ComponentModel.BindingList<MyApp.DataContracts.DatabaseInfo> GenericPreconfigs
        {
            //(Snip)
        }

        //(Snip)
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name = "DatabaseInfo", Namespace = "http://example.com/MyApp")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class DatabaseInfo : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string AllowedServer
        {
            //(Snip)
        }

        //(Snip)
    }
}
```

Applying the filter:

```
ServerSetupDTO serverSetupDTO = proxyClient.GetServerSetup();
bsServerSettings.DataSource = serverSetupDTO ;

bsPreconfigList.DataMember = "GenericPreconfigs";
bsPreconfigList.DataSource = bsServerSettings;

//This filter never gets applied, bsPreconfigList.SupportsFiltering is false.
bsPreconfigList.Filter = String.Format("AllowedServer = '{0}'", cmbHost.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

After tearing my hair out I decided to just make a ToDataSet function, as I never need to update the values.

```
public partial class ServerSetupDTO
{
    public DataSet ToDataSet()
    {

        var setupDataSet = new DataSet("ServerSetup");

        //Get the demos
        var demoPreconfigsTable = setupDataSet.Tables.Add("DemoPreconfigs");
        demoPreconfigsTable.Columns.Add("AllowedServer");
        demoPreconfigsTable.Columns.Add("SqlInstance");
        demoPreconfigsTable.Columns.Add("DatabaseName");
        this.DemoPreconfigs.ForEach(item => demoPreconfigsTable.Rows.Add(item.AllowedServer, item.SqlInstance, item.DatabaseName));

        //Get the preconfigs
        var genericPreconfigsTable = setupDataSet.Tables.Add("GenericPreconfigs");
        genericPreconfigsTable.Columns.Add("AllowedServer");
        genericPreconfigsTable.Columns.Add("SqlInstance");
        genericPreconfigsTable.Columns.Add("DatabaseName");
        this.GenericPreconfigs.ForEach(item => genericPreconfigsTable.Rows.Add(item.AllowedServer, item.SqlInstance, item.DatabaseName));

        //Get the servers
        var sqlServersTable = setupDataSet.Tables.Add("SqlServers");
        sqlServersTable.Columns.Add("ServerName");
        this.SqlServers.ForEach(item => sqlServersTable.Rows.Add(item));

        //Get the VM's
        var virtualMachinesTable = setupDataSet.Tables.Add("VirtualMachines");
        virtualMachinesTable.Columns.Add("MachineName");
        this.VirtualMachines.ForEach(item => virtualMachinesTable.Rows.Add(item));

        return setupDataSet;
    }
}
```

I then just update my one line of code to this

```
bsServerSettings.DataSource = Program.ServerSettings.ToDataSet();
```